# calloc function generating zeros instead of memory addresses

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a graph with 264346 positions. Would you know why calloc when it reaches 26,000 positions it stops generating memory addresses (ex: 89413216) and starts generating zeros (0) and then all the processes on my computer crash?

The calloc function should generate zeros but not at this position on my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>



int maxV;


struct grafo {
    int NumTotalVertices;
    int NumVertices;
    int NumArestas;
    int **p;
};
typedef struct grafo MGrafo;

MGrafo* Aloca_grafo(int NVertices);


int main(){
    MGrafo *MatrizGrafo;
    MatrizGrafo = Aloca_grafo(264346);

    return 0;
}


MGrafo* Aloca_grafo(int NVertices) {
    int i, k;
    MGrafo *Grafo ;
    Grafo = (MGrafo*) malloc(sizeof(MGrafo)); 
    Grafo->p = (int **) malloc(NVertices*sizeof(int*)); 
    
    for(i=0; i<NVertices+1; i++){
        Grafo->p[i] = (int*) calloc(NVertices,sizeof(int));// error at this point
        //printf("%d - (%d)\n", i, Grafo->p[i]); // see impression
    }
    printf("%d - (%d)\n", i, Grafo->p[i]);
    Grafo->NumTotalVertices = NVertices; 
    Grafo->NumArestas = 0; 
    Grafo->NumVertices = 0;
    return Grafo;
}
```

Comment: `NVertices` squared is a large number.

Comment: Calculate how much memory you are trying to allocate. The amount that can be allocated is not infinete.

Comment: `calloc()` can fail.  When that happens, it returns a null pointer, which may be what you are interpreting as "zero".

Comment: Perhaps because `%d` is the wrong format specifier: use `%p`. This matters very much if you have 64-bit pointers and 32-bit `int`.

Comment: Supposing that your `int`s are four bytes wide, you appear to be attempting to allocate somewhere in the vicinity of 275 GB of memory.  Machines exist that could support that, but you are unlikely to have one on your desk.  And shared machines hosted by your institution are unlikely to allow you that much at a time, even if they could, in principle, support it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Ordinary desktop machine hardware should support that today, using swap space. May just be a matter of configuring system limits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, many ordinary desktops *could* support that, but in fact they are unlikely to be configured to do so.  It's not just a matter of system limits.  Sufficient swap space / large enough page file / etc. needs to be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You surely dont mean what you have in your code

```
Grafo = (MGrafo*)malloc(sizeof(MGrafo));
Grafo->p = (int**)malloc(NVertices * sizeof(int*)); <<<<=== 264000 int pointers

for (i = 0; i < NVertices + 1; i++) {  <<<<< for each of those 264000 int pointers
    Grafo->p[i] = (int*)calloc(NVertices, sizeof(int)); <<<<<=== allocate 264000 ints
```

I ran this on my machine

- its fans turned on, meaning it was trying very very hard
- after the inner loop got to only 32000 it had already allocated 33 gb of memory

I think you only need to allocate one set of integers, since I cant tell what you are trying to do it hard to know which to remove, but this is creating a 2d array 264000 by 264000 which is huge (~70billion = ~280gb of memory), surely you dont mean that

---

OK taking a comment from below, maybe you do mean it

If this is what you really want then you are going to need a very chunky computer and a lot of time.

Plus you are definitely going to have to test the return from those calloc and malloc calls to make sure that every alloc works.

A lot of the time you will see answers on SO saying 'check the return from malloc' but in fact most modern OS with modern hardware will rarely fail memory allocations. But here you are pushing the edge, test every one.

---

'Generating zeros' is how calloc tells you it failed.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc

> Return Value
> The malloc() and calloc() functions return a pointer to the allocated memory that is suitably aligned for any kind of variable. On error, these functions return NULL. NULL may also be returned by a successful call to malloc() with a size of zero, or by a successful call to calloc() with nmemb or size equal to zero.

Comment: I'm not at all convinced that they don't mean exactly what they wrote.  For example, if they intend to represent their graph as an adjacency matrix then they indeed do need `NVertices * NVertices` matrix elements.  If they want the elements to be integer weights (as opposed to just 0 / 1) then they may indeed want elements of type `int`.

Comment: And if they want to be able to represent all graphs with `N` vertices then they do need O(`N`**2) memory, though perhaps the specific amount they need could be scaled down by use of a more efficient representation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger for fun I  let the app run to the end. It died of course ('out of memory' message from VS 'diagnostic hub') , Also my browser crashed, thats pretty bad!